# try-catch in .NET execute jQuery script

Tags: c#, jquery, html, .net

After sucessfull sending mail with asp.net I want to execute jQuery script
.NET Code:

```
void btnSubmit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) {

        MailMessage objEmail = new MailMessage();
        objEmail.To = "mymail@com";
        objEmail.From = txtFrom.Text;
        objEmail.Cc = txtCc.Text;
        objEmail.Subject = "Contact";
        objEmail.Body = "note: " + txtComments.Text + " <br> " + "name:" + txtName.Text;
        objEmail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
        objEmail.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Html;

        SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "localhost";

        try{
            SmtpMail.Send(objEmail);
            Response.Write("Email send");
        }
        catch (Exception exc){
            Response.Write("");
        }
    }
```

jQuery:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var par = $('.x');
      $(par).hide();

      $("button").click(function(){
    $(".x").toggle();

      });
    });
</script>
```

Both scripts works perfecty, but I have no idea how to combine them in order to close contact form after successful sending mail.

Here is whole contact form:

```
<div align="center"><button class="button">Napisz do nas!</button></div>
        <div class="x">

<form runat="server">
                <div align="center">
                <table border="0" width="350">
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top"><font face="Verdana" size="2">Imi&#281; i Nazwisko:</font></td>
                        <td height="20">   <asp:TextBox runat="server" Height="21px" Width="215px" ID="txtName"></asp:TextBox>
                        <br>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID = "req1" ControlToValidate = "txtFrom" Runat = "server" ErrorMessage = "Prosz&#281; poda&#263; Imi&#281; i Nazwisko "></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top"><font face="Verdana" size="2">E-mail:</font></td>
                        <td height="24"> <asp:TextBox runat="server" Height="22px" Width="213px" ID="txtFrom"></asp:TextBox>
                        <br>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID = "reg1" ControlToValidate = "txtFrom" Runat = "server" ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>&nbsp;<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID = "req3" ControlToValidate = "txtFrom" Runat = "server" ErrorMessage = "Nieprawid&#322;owy Email" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></td>
                    </tr>
                    <!--<tr>
                        <td valign="top"><font face="Verdana" size="2">To</font></td>
                        <td height="24" valign="top"> 
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" Height="22px" Width="212px" ID="txtTo"></asp:TextBox>
                        <br>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID = "reg2" ControlToValidate = "txtTo" Runat = "server" ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                        &nbsp;<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID = "req4" ControlToValidate = "txtTo" Runat = "server" ErrorMessage = "Please enter recipients E-mail" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top"><font face="Verdana" size="2">Cc</font></td>
                        <td height="24" valign="top"> 
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" Height="22px" Width="210px" ID="txtCc"></asp:TextBox>
                        <br>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID = "reg3" ControlToValidate = "txtCc" Runat = "server" ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>-->
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top"><font face="Verdana" size="2">Wiadomo&#347;&#263;:</font></td>
                        <td  height="80"> <asp:TextBox runat="server" Height="80px" TextMode="Multiline" rows="4" Width="258px" ID="txtComments"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" valign="top" height="10" align="center">
            <asp:Button Runat = server ID = btnSubmit OnClick = btnSubmit_Click Text = "Wy&#347;lij"></asp:Button>
                        &nbsp;<input type = "reset" runat = "server" value = "Wyczy&#347;&#263;"></td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                </form>

</div>
```

Comment: Where is contact form?

Comment: @Satpal - why is that necessary? Isn't this possible with [Bartdude's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20642058/1454048)?

Comment: I have added the contact form code, but I think that this is unnecessary because only option that i see is to just trigger toggle from the area of sending button, but this will always close the field, no matter if mail was send or not. If You have any ideas, I would be really happy to hear them

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time when I need to do this, I place the javascript code in a asp.net placeholder control, which I set to be invisible at page load, and change it to visible when I need to execute the javascript.

This would also allow you to handle the try, catch and finally statements by doing it with 3 different placeholders...

Answer (score 1):

What you have to remember is that the .NET code runs on the server and the jQuery code runs in the browser. There is no direct way to "call" JavaScript from .NET.

You can use the ClientScript property of the page object to inject the JavaScript into your page so that when the new page gets rendered into the browser it will contain the script and execute it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btf44dc9(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="x" runat="server">
<!-- your html -->
</div>
```

In case of successful send of email of the btnSubmit_Click:

```
x.Visible = false;
```

Comment: I have tried this option, and in case of sucesssful send of mail it make it not visible, but when it is unsuccessful it closes(but is still visible)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understood what you wrote. Can you explain it?